# Docker's container mount folder

Tags: nginx, docker, configuration, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am new to Docker and I am trying to simply launch an nginx app.

To do this, I have this DockerFile:

```
FROM debian:wheezy
MAINTAINER John Regan <john@jrjrtech.com>

RUN echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
RUN apt-key adv --fetch-keys "http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install nginx openssl ca-certificates

##Delete default repository 
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
RUN rm -rf /srv/www/*

ADD conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD conf/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD html/index.html /srv/www/index.html

VOLUME ["/etc/nginx"]
VOLUME ["/srv/www"]

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx"]
CMD []
```

My folder is organise like this:

```
├── conf
|   ├── nginx.conf
|   └── conf.d
|         └── default.conf
├── html
|   └── index.html
```

The command to launch the container:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 -v $pwd/conf:/etc/nginx -v $pwd/html:/srv/www my-nginx
```

But the conatiner stop and I got this message in the log:

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/mime.types" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:14
```

I know that the log is pretty clear, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are mounting your `conf` dir your are replacing the contents of the `/etc/nginx` dir. instead mount the `nginx.conf` file and the `conf/conf.d` -  see the section on mounting files, https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockervolumes/

`sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 -v $pwd/conf/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d -v $pwd/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -v $pwd/html:/srv/www my-nginx`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the configuration on the in the nginx.conf is correct? The error seems related to nginx not to the docker.

Answer (score 0):

The "volume" option, mount a new point of directory, you should've specifics if you need mount only a file.